# setInterval loop doesn't wait at await

Tags: javascript, async-await, setinterval

I made an example function 'webrequest()', imagine that this is a webrequest that takes 2 to get a response. I want to send a new webrequest after each response I receive. When I run te loop it just doesn't wait at the await and it sends another webrequest.

I have no idea what I did wrong. I can't find posts about this problem(maybe i'm searching wrong).

```
function webrequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve()
        },2000)
    })
}

function loopTest() {
setInterval(async () => {
    console.log('Welcome')
    await webrequest();
    console.log('Bye')
},10)
}

loopTest()
```

So the output should be.

```
Welcome
(2 seconds timeout)
Bye
Welcome
(2 seconds timeout)
Bye
...
```

Comment: setInterval runs the function at the specified interval, it doesn't wait for completion. You have to use setTimeout instead, and schedule a new timeout after the `await` line.

Comment: ^ what he said.  also, if you are dead-set on using setInterval you can do `var a = setInterval(...)` and then do `clearInterval(a)` inside just before the `await` then do another `a = setInterval(...)` directly after

Comment: You should use `while (true) { await  webRequest(); await delay(10); }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense in using a short running `setInterval` then. Just use a loop:

```
  (async function() {
     while(true) {
       console.log('Welcome')
       await webrequest();
       console.log('Bye')
     }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above setInterval does not play well with promises if you do not stop it. In case you clear the interval you can use it like:

It seems that it's setTimeout that fits the case. It should be isside promise in order to be used with async..await:

```js
function first(){
  console.log('Welcome')
}
function second(){
  console.log('Bye')
}
async function loopTest(){
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(first()), 1000));
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(second()), 1000));
}

loopTest()
```